Country map - ISO_3166_2 - Zagorje ob Savi - SI-142 not showing
If you use country map for slovenia
and have some data for 'SI-142' (Municipality of Zagorje ob Savi)
Data is not shown. All other municipalities are working.


I tried the previous code (before 1995) SI-5561 but no success there

Based on file
https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/superset-frontend/plugins/legacy-plugin-chart-country-map/src/countries/slovenia.geojson
the error looks like 'SI-05' to actually be 'SI-142'
